# mpm_prefork:error Cannot allocate memory

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I was using a website called loadimpact to test how my php application would perform under a big amount of access. I did one really small test with only 50 virtual users accessing at the same time, and I noticed that after a while all the requests were returning a 502 status code. Even after the test was done the I couldn't access the website anymore, also getting a 502 error. It came back to normal after I restarted the server.

I checked the server logs and I saw the following message:

```
[mpm_prefork:error] [pid 3189] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
```

I assume this is because the server runned out of memory, but I'm not sure. I also noticed the server CPU usage peaked during the same time.

I did the test two more times after I the server restart and it worked flawlessly, no memory error nor 502 response.

My app is built using Laravel and I use AWS Elastic Beanstalk as my aws server and an RDS instance as my database. It is a t2.micro instance. The only custom configuration I have is a crontab running a scheduled task on the background.

I do basically 3 things when the page I tested is accessed: I log the access on the database, I setup a cookie for user tracking and I load some stuff from the db.

I was planning on testing the server capacity because I am working on a deal with a bigger company that will generate a lot more access on the website, but now I am worried that this happens again, since I am not sure the cause of this.

Do anyone have any idea what might have caused this error?

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely an out of memory error on your server. A t2.micro is pretty cramped for a Apache/PHP installation under load. How much 'stuff' is being read from the DB?

I've also seen certain kinds of application errors cause PHP to go into an infinite-recursion error such that no amount of memory will satisfy it; however much you have will be slightly less than the amount it asks for.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that the t2.micro is a small instance that won't deliver me much in terms of capacity but my application do not have much access yet(it still in it's early stages). 

From the database I load basically a small list of Itens (no more than 20 itens) from one table and a single row from another table, and I am even caching those values. 
I double checked for infinite loops but on the code run by this particular page it seems all fine. What bugs me is that it only happened once, all my tests with the same load I did afterwards worked without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in `top` or `ps aux` output for how much memory each apache process is using.  Multiply this by 50 to figure out roughly how much memory you will need to serve 50 simultaneous users.

Using the worker or event Apache MPMs with PHP as a separate CGI process pool instead of the prefork MPM with mod_php can help make more efficient use of memory.

You can also reduce memory usage by removing Apache modules and PHP extensions.  What you do in the PHP code also affects memory usage and you can use the memory functions within PHP to profile this.

At some point, you will have to either choose an instance type with more RAM or spread the load out over multiple instances.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try changing the configuration as you mentioned and minimize the Apache and PHP modules being load, thanks for the tip. 

But what I thinks is weird is the fact that the same test succeeded after I restarted the server. If the server was unable to handle the access it should be unable everytime. I even checked the memory usage during my subsequent tests (I didn't check during the one that failed be I wasn't expecting it to) and it didn't even got very high, it looked like I could even scale the test to 70 virtual users without much problems.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve your problem as such, but it will help you work around it.

Two of the great things about Cloud Computing are elasticity and automation. Elasticity means if your server slows down or fails you can easily start another server, or another 50 servers. Automation means it can all be done without your direct input. AWS Elastic Beanstalk supports both of these.

You need to [enable load balancing and auto scaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html#using-features.managing.changetype) and [configure a health check](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html). This way if your server starts returning error codes it will be able to route traffic to healthy servers, stop the failing server, and create a new server in its place. If you need 1 server to service your load you probably need to keep 2 servers running in order to have a reliable system. You could put these servers in different AZs to give yourself a more reliable system, ideally with a multi-AZ RDS database.

Answer (score 0):

Jumping Jehosaphat!?! Only 50 users? What size instance are you using for your cloud webserver?

There is some good advice here. First, learn how the different MPM modules function and their intent. Prefork can get nasty on system resources. Tuning for performance is always needed. I would guess you have an untuned Apache and PHP. Look at the modules you need and remove anything else! There is truly no need for Apache to have the memory footprint it does, with everything included and enabled. Do you use WebDAV? Similarly with PHP. Look at the modules you use and remove everything else. Do you use PostGRES DB?

Tuning your Linux system for performance is also needed. Out of the 'box' (I know, there's no box ... it's just a phrase) Linux isn't tuned to behave like a server that takes a decent amount of traffic. You want to close unused TCP connections sooner than 4 minutes, I'd bet. Most websites do...
Every connection needs RAM! Keeping them open just in case that long makes no sense. Not in the modern world with broadband connections to the home.

You can scale up your cloud instance to solve the problem, sure. However doing this doesn't actually fix diddly-squat! You'll have to pay out the nose for a cloud instance with OBSCENE amounts of system memory and cpu cores just to keep running.
Tune it to work properly and you can do the same thing with a much smaller cloud instance!

I've taken C4-4xLarge instances that were crashing and running out of memory taking 100 concurrent connections and moved that to a tuned M4-xlarge that could do 300 concurrent connections to the website. No more OOM crashes!

Make a copy of your running configuration file, keep track of what you comment out or uninstall, just in case you need to put it back!
Look at the PHP modules you have installed. I'd bet you don't need 80% of them. Similar with the Apache modules. Do you need it???
If you tweak that and still need more, you can go further, but it gets tediouser (I know, that isn't in Webster's, but it's a legit word)